# Do I need close InputStream of HttpUrlConnection if I never call getInputStream?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

The scenario is I only need to read some values from the HTTP response header. So I never called the `httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()` or `httpUrlConnection.getContentLength()`.

Do I need add `httpUrlConnection.getInputStream().close();` ?

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        String dateStr = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Date");
        Date date =
                new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US).parse(dateStr);
        long timeMillis = date.getTime();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course you could call `urlConnection.setDoInput(false);`. But just disconnecting the connection should suffice.

Comment: You have implicitly called `connect()` by calling `getHeaderField()`, just as `getInputStream()`, does, so yes you need to close it. Otherwise you will leak the connection. Unless you call `disconnect()`, as you have, but that kills connection re-use.